# Tweetinvi keep stream alive

Tags: twitter, tweetinvi

I run my web app using Amazon EC2 servers and use TweetInvi to maintain a user and filtered twitter stream. I need the streams to be running 24/7.

I am using the StreamStopped event to keep the stream running continuously as described here:

[How to keep streaming continuously - Tweetinvi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319449/how-to-keep-streaming-continuously-tweetinvi)

I am starting the stream in my startup class by using hangfire (http://hangfire.io/) to maintain the stream connection in the background but happy to do this any other way.

My application is kept alive 24/7 if no users connect.

However, after a while, with no exception raised, the streams stop.

Is there a better way to maintain and keep alive a stream?

Comment: When you say the stream stops, are you suggesting that the `StreamStopped` event is not raised?

Comment: I think so yes. Not sure if my approach is right to maintain a 24/7 stream.

Answer (score 0):

My keep-alive function wasn't actually working 100% and so my application sometimes died during the night when no users connected hence the StreamStopped event wasn't called. I now use Uptime Robot to hit my site every minute keeping it alive.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. Was the fault on the Tweetinvi side or on your side?

Comment: Mine - simply when the application timed out during inactivity the StreamStopped event could not possibly be called.

Comment: thanks - so far Tweetinvi has been brilliant, would recommend to anyone.

Comment: @SSED How did you use the hangfire? Did you create the stream in the hangfire job?